# blacklist feature in amavis

Tags: linux, anti-virus

Hiii......

I want to block email from specific sender using amavisd- new

Comment: how to configure the amavis with postfix and how can do the feature of whilelist/blacklist????

Answer (score 1):

About configuring: http://howtoforge.com/amavisd_postfix_debian_ubuntu

If you are not using Ubuntu/Debian just replace installation section commands (apt-get ...) with your distro package management commands or ignore it if you have everything already installed.

Note that if you want just block some specific sender, there are other ways. For example, header_checks filter for Postfix. Add this to /etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
```

Then edit the file /etc/postfix/header_checks and add the line like this:

```
/^From: blocked@sender\.address/       REJECT
```

Read `man header_checks` and `man regexp_table` to get more ideas if needed.

If you still want to blacklist senders with Amavis, there are two ways: hard blacklisting (that is, complete blocking of certain senders) and adding Spamassassin score points for those senders.

For some reason, hard blacklisting works only via SQL lookups. If you want to use this approach and if you have Amavis set up to work with SQL lookups, find variable $sql_select_white_black_list in /etc/amavisd.conf and replace 'undef' with an appropriate database query. Setting up Amavis, database and database tables for this is far beyond the scope of a short answer like this. You can find tutorials on howtoforge.com.

To setup Spamassassin blacklisting, find variable @score_sender_maps in /etc/amavisd.conf. There are a variety of methods to let Amavis know what senders should be blacklisted: hash assigned to this variable, a separate file, SQL lookup. I don't want to describe all these details because /etc/amavisd.conf is **very** well commented. So all needed info and examples can be found in /etc/amavisd.conf right around the variables I mentioned above.

If your particular distro has amavisd.conf without comments (I've seen that once, but I don't remember what distro it was), download Amavis sources and find fully commented amavisd.conf inside the tarball.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Try out this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixAmavisNew

All The Best